# Python relative import error?

Tags: python, django, import, package

ı have a django project and i need to access some of models in my folder that under the django main project folder.Let me illustrate this.

```
    src\
        main\
            urls.py
            models.py
            view.py
        lib\
            __init__.py
            helper.py
```

This is the example folder structure and i need to import some class of main app's models inside the helper.py.I tried these:

```
           from main.models import exampleClass
           from ..main.models import exampleClass
```

And i also tried adding a `__init__.py` file in the main project folder:

```
           src\
               ...
               main\
               lib\
               __init__.py
```

Always errors 2 kind :

1)ValueError : relative import error
2) no module name..

I need the solution and need good explanation why i failed always.Thank you so much guys.

Answer (score 1):

Add `__init__.py` in `main` folder instead of `src` folder. Then try to import using `from main.models import exampleClass`. It should be working.

Comment: i am sorry main folder already have __init__.py cuz it is an app.but i need some edit for my question or i can write here i am trying to use the helper.py on terminal via $ python helper.py

Answer (score 0):

How did you set $PYTHONPATH variable ? The search paths are relative to this environment variable.

So if you want to specify a path like `main.models`, it should contain the `src` directory.

Note that you can also manage it with the `sys.path` array.

Django normally add all the applications to `sys.path`. You may try to print it inside the `settings.py` file to have an idea.

To add a path from the settings.py file of the project, you could do something like:

```
import os.path
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
sys.path.append(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "../lib"))
```

If for example you have a `lib` directory at the same level as the directory that contains the `settings.py` file.

Comment: i feel you are goint to answer me :) . i wrote $ echo $PYTHONPATH on terminal and shows nothing.How can i specify folders inside this or i wonder how sys.path works for packages.

Comment: let say i added the "/home/me/desktop/test" to $PYTHONPATH.so now what that is mean ?

Comment: `$PYTHONPATH` is not always set nor required. Did you try to print `sys.path` inside one of the Python scripts ?

Comment: I added some info in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `..` if `main` and `lib` are both django's apps, and you have registered them in `INSTALLED_APPS` settings.

If `main` and `lib` are in the same level that `manage.py`:

```
src/
    main/
        ...
    lib/
        ...
    manage.py
    ...
```

You just need:

```
from main.models import exampleClass
```

Comment: thank you but lib is not an app just folder that contains my helper functions.

Comment: @sj_magento give it a try.